# What's good UX for selecting an item from a list of potentially 20k+ items?

Tags: web-app, many-options

Each client using the site has different options in that list, gotten from the client themselves. A normal select field works for most clients (who have between 5-10k options). A few, though, go all the way to 20k+ which causes the browser to lock up for a bit when the page loads.

What would be an alternative to a native select field for showing that many options?

Comment: Do people know what they are looking for,like can they search for it?

Comment: They sometimes do, sometimes don't. I will be adding search to it, but they still need to be able to browse through the list. :/

Comment: like would they atleast know the first few charecters of an item they are looking for say AT3 where the item might be At3034223424

Comment: I think so, yeah. I was considering showing a list of letters by default, clicking a letter loads all options that start with that letter. That way I'm only having 1-2k options in the list at once. Searching would basically do the same.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the items? Are they hierarchical? Do they have categories?

Comment: What are your use cases like? Do users already know the name of thing they're searching for? Have they seen the name before but may not recognize it until they see it? Have they never seen the name before? Even when I have lists that are 1700 items long, I offer multiple ways to get to the info. e.g., by letter groupings, plus by type ahead search that lets the user select from suggestions or execute the search, plus also by browsing the names put into topical categories. Can you offer multiple options for your users' multiple info seeking behaviors?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly select an item from such a large list. Lots of information always confuses, so we need to give user a clear path to completion. There are at least two ways to deal with it:

1. Some kind of smart search, or "advanced search" with different options. It would be also good to show information in process about how much items matches your request.
2. Separating the content with some kind of categories or narrow filters, to decrease the amount of items to choose, and to give a clear way, how to choose and find items.

To give more appropriate answer, it would be good, if you'll give more detailed information about what kind of items and item types can be there in your case.

Answer (score 2):

The usability of a normal select field is greatly reduced for any list involving 5 items or more (yes - 5, not 5k). These components are as old as the web and were never designed with usability in mind.

However, they are great when you want to put strict constraints on the input (like when users choose a month for the expiry field of a credit card in a payment form).

But the task of visually inspecting more than 20 text items, let alone 5K can quickly become a cognitive nightmare. The fact that you can search using keys is little obvious and involves no feedback to the user.

You should look for:

- **Typeahead** option (aka suggestion or smart select).
- **Remote** search (so not all data is streamed to the client).
- **Fuzzy** search (a type of search that can yield better matches if users don't type the query letter-by-letter as the match).

The most famous component I know of is [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/):

[image: A screengrab of the select2 component - an input field with suggestions based on the query typed]

ExtJS also has [such component](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/form/forum-search.html):

[image: ExtJs live search, with more evolved search options and pagination]

There are many other.

Comment: I think it should be more like a form with some kind of filtering, not the only search/list field, becouse if you'll have similar names it would be still to large list of items as a result, and the only way to handle it would be to know exactly, what is the name of the item.